# Grafana via reverse proxy in IIS

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, prometheus, grafana

I have trouble exposing grafana via reverse proxy in IIS.
Grafana config is:

```
http_addr =
http_port = 3000
domain = stats.mydomain.com:80
enforce_domain = false
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s/grafana/
serve_from_sub_path = true
static_root_path = public
```

I successfully navigate to http://localhost:3000/grafana/ and browse the graphs it serves.

In iis, i registered the stats.mydomain.com website as a new website, then created a rewrite rule according to official guide:
[iis rewrite rule for grafana](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcofd.png)

However, when i navigate to http://stats.mydomain.com/grafana/, i get a 404 error.
When I navigate to same website from server, the error is 404 and sub-error code is 4.

May I please know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to do this following Grafana's official guide located at https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/tutorials/iis/

But I was able to do this following a guide on Microsoft, located here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222#